# How to get a name of the user, resposible for triggering workflow in github actions

Tags: github-actions

We have notifications on deployments, which are send to the corporate chat. When user run code locally, there is some amount of information to identify 'who run the code' ($USER, $HOSTNAME, etc).

When the same code is triggered from CI, I would like to have information on 'who is the cause' for this workflow. It may be a github account name for the user to click on `workflow_dispatch', or author for commit in git, or author or PR, etc.

Is there such info available to workflows in Github Actions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might be interested by the [Github Context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) concept.

There, you'll see that on each workflow, you can access context variables, such as the `github.actor` variable to access **the login of the user** that initiated the workflow run.

> **TIP**: You can print the workflow `GitHub variables` using the following step:
>
> ```
> - name: Show GitHub context   
>   env: 
>     GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}   
>   run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
>   shell: bash
> ```
>
> Otherwise, here is a [payload sample](https://gist.github.com/colbyfayock/1710edb9f47ceda0569844f791403e7e) to know what are the available variables.

Comment: Yes, this thing. Thank you!

Comment: Actually now it won't work. 1st: you have to set `shell: bash` (or any other); 2nd: the ``` at the end are failing. It's better to put it into a new line and `run: |`